# Why does the typescript compiler silently exit on a .ts file starting with a hash character?

Tags: typescript

If I compile the following file

**test.ts**

```
#   
class Test {
}
```

with

```
tsc test.ts
```

no output file is produced and the compiler does not give any warnings or errors. Running the compiler with debug turned on

```
tsc --debug test.ts
```

yields the following output:

```
Reading code from /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts
Found code at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts
Reading code from /tmp/ts/directives/test.ts
Found code at /tmp/ts/directives/test.ts
```

If I put the hash line after the class declaration

**test2.ts**

```
class Test {
}
#
```

the compiler reports no errors and generates output file

**test2.js**

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() { }
    return Test;
})();
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I have filed an issue at [codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/270).

Comment: A somewhat related SO question: [How to make a shell executable node file using TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23298295/82216).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed on the developer branch (0.8). Characters such as @ or # no longer block compilation. Please check the latest compiler.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a bug. This should be an error, as you expect.